# How to convert KeyCode.E to UIButton

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-button

i want to change if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) with UIButton and I can't, help me...

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Item"))
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                playerInventory.item.Add(GetComponent<Item>());
                Destroy(col.transform.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you would use the `Item` component of the object this script is attached to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would assume for now that you actually would want to use `col.GetComponent<Item>()` instead of trying to get the component from the very same object this script is attached to.

And then instead of using `OnTriggerStay` you could instead do something like

```c#
private readonly HashSet<Item> currentTriggeredItems = new HashSet<Item>(); 

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Item") && col.TryGetComponent<Item>(out var item))
    {
        if(!currentTriggeredItems.Contains(item)) currentTriggeredItems.Add(item);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Item") && col.TryGetComponent<Item>(out var item))
    {
        if(currentTriggeredItems.Contains(item)) currentTriggeredItems.Remove(item);
    }
}

// This is the method you reference in the UI.Button.onClick
public void OnUiButtonClicked()
{
    foreach(var item in currentTriggeredItems)
    {
        playerInventory.item.Add(item);
        Destroy(item.gameObject)
    }

    currentTriggeredItems.Clear();
}
```